# Is it possible to add a dropdown product sort inside custom WP_Query?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

So I wrote a custom query, what it does is that it returns all the products based on what manufacturer the user clicks. (e.g when the user clicks 'ABC' manufacturer, the browser will redirect to the manufacturer taxonomy page and it will display all the manufacturer's products).

This is my code

```
<?php $args = array('post_type' => 'product',
                    'posts_per_page' => 9,
                    'tax_query' => array(
                            array('taxonomy' => 'pa_manufacturer',
                                    'terms' => get_queried_object()->slug,
                                    'field' => 'slug',
                                    'operator' => 'IN')));
       $queried_products = new WP_Query($args);
       if($queried_products->have_posts()): while($queried_products->have_posts()): $queried_products->the_post();?>
             <div class="col-md-4">
                 <a href="<?php the_permalink($queried_products->post->ID);?>">
                       <?php $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_post_thumbnail_id($queried_products->post->ID), 'full');?>
                       <div class="product-image-wrap">
                          <img src="<?php echo $image[0];?>" class="img-fluid">
                       </div>
                       <p class="product-name"><?php echo $queried_products->post->post_title;?></p>    
                 </a>
             </div>
<?php endwhile; endif;?>
```

Is it possible to add a dropdown sort above it?

[image]

Comment: I think that this is possible using Ajax on this dropdown field, if you don't want to submit/reload the page for filtering… So it's a bit complicated. But searching a bit, you will find some tutorials or useful code for that.

Comment: Answer : Yes, it is possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's my updated solution on this. I wrote an AJAX function for the dropdown sorting.

**Here's the JQuery code for triggering the event.**

```
jQuery('#filter').change(function(){
    var filter_val = jQuery(this).val();
    var slug = jQuery('#slug').val();
    jQuery.ajax({
        method: 'POST',
        url: filter_ajax.ajax_url,
        data: {
            'action': 'product_filter',
            'filter': filter_val,
            'slug': slug
        },
        beforeSend: function(){
            jQuery('div#loading').fadeIn();
        },
        success: function(data){
            jQuery('#results-wrap').html(data);
            jQuery('div#loading').fadeOut();
        }
    })  
});
```

**Here's the AJAX Code**

```
add_action('wp_ajax_product_filter', 'product_filter');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_product_filter', 'product_filter');

function product_filter(){
    $html = '';
    if(!empty($_POST['filter'])){
        $filter_val = explode('-', $_POST['filter']);
        $sequence = ($filter_val[1] == 'highest') ? 'DESC' : 'ASC';
        $meta_val = '';

    if($filter_val[0] == 'date'){
        $meta_val = 'date';
        if($filter_val[1] == 'newest'){
            $sequence = 'ASC';
        }else{
            $sequence = 'DESC';
        }
        $filter_val[0] = '';
    }else{
        $meta_val = 'meta_value_num';
    }

    $args = array('post_type' => 'product',
            'posts_per_page' => 9,
            'tax_query' => array(
                array('taxonomy' => 'pa_manufacturer',
                    'terms' => $_POST['slug'],
                    'field' => 'slug',
                    'operator' => 'IN')
            ),
            'orderby' => $meta_val,
            'meta_key' => $filter_val[0],
            'order' => $sequence);
    $queried_products = new WP_Query($args);

    $html .= '<div class="row">';

    if($queried_products->have_posts()):
        while($queried_products->have_posts()):
            $queried_products->the_post();
            $html .= '<div class="col-md-4">';
            $html .= '<a href="' . get_the_permalink($queried_products->post->ID) . '">';
            $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_post_thumbnail_id($queried_products->post->ID), 'full');
            $html .= '<div class="product-image-wrap">';
            $html .= '<img src="' .  $image[0] . '" class="img-fluid">';
            $html .= '</div>';
            $html .= '<p class="product-name">' . $queried_products->post->post_title . '</p>';   
            $html .= '</a>';
            $html .= '</div>';
        endwhile;
    else:
        $html .= '<div class="no-results">';
        $html .= '<h1><i class="fa fa-frown-o" aria-hidden="true"></i><span class="inline-middle">No Results Found.</span></h1>';
        $html .= '</div>';
    endif;
    $html .= '</div>';
}
die($html);
}
```

**Here's the updated HTML code.**

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo home_url($wp->request);?>" id="product-filter">
                        <select name="filter" id="filter" class="postform">
                            <option selected="selected">Sort By</option>
                            <option value="_price">Lowest Price</option>
                            <option value="_price-highest">Highest Price</option>
                            <option value="date-newest">Newest to Oldest</option>
                            <option value="date">Oldest to Newest</option>
                        </select>
                        <input name="slug" id="slug" type="hidden" value="<?php echo get_queried_object()->slug;?>">
                    </form>

                    <div id="results-wrap">

                        <?php $args = array('post_type' => 'product',
                            'posts_per_page' => 9,
                            'tax_query' => array(
                            array('taxonomy' => 'pa_manufacturer',
                                'terms' => get_queried_object()->slug,
                                'field' => 'slug',
                                'operator' => 'IN')));
                            $queried_products = new WP_Query($args);?>

                        <div class="row">
                            <?php if($queried_products->have_posts()): while($queried_products->have_posts()): $queried_products->the_post();?>
                            <div class="col-md-4">
                                <a href="<?php the_permalink($queried_products->post->ID);?>">
                                    <?php $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_post_thumbnail_id($queried_products->post->ID), 'full');?>
                                    <div class="product-image-wrap">
                                        <img src="<?php echo $image[0];?>" class="img-fluid">
                                    </div>
                                    <p class="product-name"><?php echo $queried_products->post->post_title;?></p>   
                                </a>
                            </div>
                            <?php endwhile; endif;?>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```